# jQuery Mobile: data-rel="back" does not work properly after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

On my jQuery mobile page I have two pages: Page A and B. Page A contains a tab boxes container. Each box contains a different text with a link to page B.

**Page A:**

```
 <div id="testtab-con">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="tab1">Testtab #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="tab2">Testtab #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="tab3">Testtab #3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1" class="testtab">
            <p>Content Tab 1</p>
            <a href="http://www.mypage.com/pageB">link to page B</a>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="testtab" style="display:none">
            <p>Content Tab 2</p>
            <a href="http://www.mypage.com/pageB">link to page B</a>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="testtab" style="display:none">
            <p>Content Tab 3</p>
            <a href="http://www.mypage.com/pageB">link to page B</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#testtab-con li a').on('click', function() {
            var targetTab = $(this).attr('title');

            $('.testtab').hide();
            $('#' + targetTab).show();
        })
    </script>
```

**Page B:**

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn" data-rel="back">back</a>

<p>Content of page B... ... ...</p>
```

**My problem:**

When on page A I select the second tab and from there go to page B, I would like to have the second tab still being visible when I return to page A via the data-rel="back" button *even when the user has reloaded page B*. However, after reloading page B, when the user clicks the back button and returns to page A, the second tab is not set visible anymore, but the first one.

How do I achieve in jQuery Mobile that my tab selection on page A is remembered when from page B after reload (!) the user goes back to page A?

Answer (score 0):

you can set dom-cache as true, to not reload your page A :

```
<div data-dom-cache="true" data-role="page">
    ...
</div>
```

Another way :

add a function to your link like :

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn" onclick="switch_page('page_b','page_a');">back</a>

<script>
function switch_page(page_current, page_target){
    $('#'+page_current).hide();
    $('#'+page_target).show();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)** to save the currently selected tab and reload when pageA is reloaded:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageA", function(){ 

    var savedTab = sessionStorage.getItem('selTab');
    if ($('#' + savedTab).length == 1){
        $('.testtab').hide();
        $('#' + savedTab).show();        
    }

    $('#testtab-con li a').on('click', function() {
        var targetTab = $(this).attr('title');
        sessionStorage.setItem('selTab', targetTab);

        $('.testtab').hide();
        $('#' + targetTab).show();
    });

});
```

If you want to reload the same tab between sessions, you can use localStorage instead of sessionStorage.